# GREL round up number and be divisible by 5

Tags: math, openrefine, grel

In OpenRefine I have a data set and I would like to round the number to the closest value and can be divided by 5 (divisible by 5).

For example:

```
1.35 would be 1.50
1.70 would be 2.00
```

I have looked [into the documentation](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Math-Functions) but couldn't figure out how to achieve that.

Comment: Your example data doesn' t match your question. The answer for both of them should be 5 if you are looking to round up to the nearest multiple of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your numbers are all integers, you could do:

```
floor((value+4)/5)*5
```

If it's possible that you'll get floating point numbers too, you could modify it along the lines of:

```
floor((value+4.999)/5)*5
```

Comment: What about larger numbers? (like `334` or `344`, the formula doesn't seems to work). I mean if the value is `334` the the rounded number should be `335`.

Comment: I didn't notice that your example data didn't match your problem description. Do you want things to be divisible by 5 like the text says or 0.5 as the example data shows?

Comment: I just want to display values like (`335` instead of `334`, `345` instead of `344`). Not sure if I've got your question